# Performance issues when reloading entity

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, objectcontext

We are switching from ObjectContext to DbContext in your EF6 desktop application. At the moment I struggle with reloading data from the DB without recreating the whole context. Unfortunately we work partly with a long living context approach which I can't change easily.

To reload the properties of an entity (without the navigation properties) with the newest values from the database (store wins), we use `CreateObjectSet()` with `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges` from the `ObjectContext`. I am now trying to replace it with a `DbContext` alternative.

I have found the following options:

- `DbContext.Entry(entity).Reload()`
- Overwrite the values of each property in the entity using the values from `DbContext.Entry(entity).GetDatabaseValues()`
- Detaching the entity and fetch it again e.g. using `Find()`

Even when disabling `AutoDetectChanges` all these options are still much slower as when using `CreateObjectSet()`. By the way: Creating a new context and fetch the values again would be slower too but not that much.

Am I missing something or does `DbContext` not have a performant alternative (apart from creating a new context) for `CreateObjectSet()` with `StoreWins`?

Comment: You want entity to be forward/backward compatible and it may take more processing to run older version on newer machine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. There is no "old" or "new" machine. DbContext seems to be slower than ObjectContext concerning reloading data with StoreWins. I wonder whether this is really the case or whether I miss something.

Comment: I meant old configuration and new configuration.